# Laravel convert collect() to object dynamically

Tags: php, laravel, collections, laravel-8

I need to create a collection from an array in Laravel and use `->` to access my `domain` key, I've tried:

- `all()`
- `first()`
- `get()`

What am I missing?

```php
$domain = collect([
    'domain' => 'test'
])->first();
```

I need to be able to use this syntax: `$domain->domain` which would then give me "test".

Comment: Right now you've got a single-dimension array, so it's returning the first value, which is `test`. You can turn it into an array of arrays, but you still wouldn't be able to use `$domain->domain` because the first element would be an array, not an object.

Comment: Try `$domain = collect(['domain' => 'test'])->pluck('domain');`

Comment: @Jérôme your suggested solution returns `{domain: 0: null}`

Comment: Why not just use `$domain["domain"]` since you've created an array?

Answer (score 1):

```
$domains = collect([(object)['domain' => 'test']]);
$domain = $domains->first();

// OR $domain = collect([(object)['domain' => 'test']])->first();

$domain->domain; // 'test'`
```

The `(object)[...]` syntax is called [casting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting), and allows you to set certain variables as an explicit type, if possible. This code will create a `Collection` of a single `Object`, with a single property `domain: 'Test'`, which you can access via `->` syntax.

Note, if you're working with Models, you can use either `->` or `[]` syntax:

```
$domains = Domain::get();

$domain = $domains->first();

$domain->domain; // 'test'
$domain['domain']; // 'test'
```